# MAF Sensor Performance Code in cold weather

Tags: nissan, maf, p0101, murano

I have a 2011 Nissan Murano with a check engine light that comes on and off.  It started once the weather started turning cold, however the check engine light will disappear shortly after I get my OBD codes checked and weather gets above freezing again.  It is the same code every time, P0101, Mass Air Flow Circuit/Range Performance Problem.

I have tried taking it out and spraying it with MAF Sensor cleaner once and that caused the code to go away for a week or so however it came right back.

I don't happen to notice any engine performance problems or idling problem at all.  I don't notice any other exhaust symptoms that would indicate a PCV valve issue either.  (I happen to have a replacement PCV valve because they were really cheap but apparently it is extraordinarily difficult to replace because of where it is located)

Before I spend $80 on a new MAF sensor, I wanted to see if there is anything I am possibly missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, temperature should not affect the operation of the MAF unless it gets *very cold* (like -40° C or F - take your pick). I'd suggest if you the MAF code keeps popping, even after cleaning, your MAF is most likely at fault. The only thing you might be able to do is to try a different MAF sensor and see if that fixes the issue. The problem with this is, if you buy one thinking you can return it, in most cases you can't. The only other way is to find someone else with your same vehicle and swap out sensors temporarily. You might also be able to find one at a junk yard (breaker's, whatever you want to call it), but that's a hit or miss proposition and the expense of it will probably be close to a new sensor.

Before you buy one, you could also check to ensure there's nothing wrong with the wiring. Check the connector, making sure it's clean and without corrosion.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I suppose I could try cleaning the connector.  Do you think the MAF Sensor spray cleaner would be safe to spray in the connector to clean the contacts?

Comment: @maple_shaft - Absolutely. It dries clean and clear.

Comment: you aren't getting a broken signal.  I doubt the wiring could be at fault.